Inference of stratified simple random sampling
I would like to estimate the population probability $p$ using stratified random sampling because my data consists of many stratas $h$.
In this case, if we select total $n$ samples, the optimal number of samples per layer $n_h$ is optimized as follows
$n_h = n\cdot \sqrt{T_h} /(\sum_h \sqrt{T_h})$
Where $T_h$ is as follows
$T_h = (N_h/N)^2({{N_h}\over{N_h -1}}p_h(1-p_h))$
Where $N$ is total population and $N_h$ is number of each strata, $p_h$ is the true probability of each strata. therefore, when determining the optimal number of samples $n_h$ from each strata $h$ using stratified random sampling, it is assumed that the true probabilities of each strata $p_h$ are already known. $n_h$ depends on the strata size $N_h$ and probability $p_h$, so if $N_h$ is large, we sample more. Also, if $p_h$ is around 0.5, in other words, if variance is large, we sample more.
Then I wonder what makes it meaningful to sample and inference using stratified simple random sampling? Since we assume that we know the probabilities of stratas in the population in order to determine the optimal number of samples, then isn't it possible to find out the probability of the population using $p_h$?
So I just thought on my own that.. we do not assume that we know exactly $p_h$, but we almost know that (maybe with error around 5%?), and calculate population using sampling.
